# Delay on Rendering and loading my fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, delay

In my MainActivity I have 3 Fragments that show and hide them by Buttons and never destroy them. when i start another activity and get back to MainActivity i have a delay to load and render one of my fragments . 
any idea to reduce the delay ?
Thanks.